# C# : When modifying a tablelayoutpanel, controls in another tablelayoutpanel disappear

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

The two tableLayoutPanels have nothing in common.

In the first one, adding a specific row just makes all the Labels (and not the others controls) of the second tableLayoutPanel dissapear!

Has anyone encountered this problem? Solved it?

Comment: Design time?  Run time?  Dynamically created controls?  Post repro steps.

Comment: Runtime. The controls disappearing have been made with the designer. Those being added to the first TableLayoutPanel, programmatically.

Comment: Try to reproduce it in a small App. 10:1 you will find your error along the way. If not, post some code here. Right now this is to vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I encountered this problem more than once. It regards to resource writer. If you have two different TLP's, modifying one will actually overwrite settings (which are kept in *.resx file) for another.

I googled it like half year ago and it seems that there are few people who had this problem - it happens IIRC in VS 2005 SP3 and VS 2008 SP2.

I don't think there is anything that could be done except preserving backup copy of the resx file and merging it after making the changes. Or upgrading to VS 2010 that allegedly does not have this defect (but I haven't actually tested it, so I might be totally wrong).